# Hide UIImageView from UITableViewCell for Core Data entries that do not exist

Tags: ios, core-data, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am in the middle of updating my app from an App Store version to a new version. My App is a simple `UITableViewController` that gets populated by the user clicking on a `UINavigationBar` button item and adding in information into `UITextFields`. When the user saves, the information gets saved to Core Data and the `UITableViewController` gets populated with `NSFetchedResultsController`.

The Model is simple: Transaction Entity with a notes attribute (there are others, but that's not relevant).

The existing App Store version does not have the ability for the user to create notes, but the new version does, with a `UITextView` in the Add Entry screen.

If the entry has a note, the `UITableViewCell` contains a pin image.

The pin is working throughout the app, but if I update from the App Store version to the new version, it shows a pin on all cells which should not be possible, considering they would of course not have notes. I know I'm missing something easy here but I can't quite figure it out:

This code is in my `cellForRow`:

```
self.pin = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 30, 24, 25)];
self.pin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin"];
self.pin.tag = 777;

if (!transaction.notes)
{
    NSLog(@"No notes");
    [[customCell viewWithTag:777] removeFromSuperview];

}

if ([transaction.notes isEqualToString:@""] || ([transaction.notes isEqualToString:@" "] || ([transaction.notes isEqualToString:@"  "] || ([transaction.notes isEqualToString:@"   "]))))
{
    NSLog(@"Remove Notes");
    [[customCell viewWithTag:777] removeFromSuperview];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Notes");
    [customCell addSubview:self.pin];

}
```

I'm initialising the self.pin in the `viewDidLoad` and the `viewWillAppear` as well.

I've added in the first if statement because in my head, the cells before the update should not have any notes.

When I run this code, all of the cells continue to have the pin the first time the app is run after the update.

Any guidance on fixing this issue would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the UI on the Main Thread:

```
if (!transaction.notes) {
 dispatch_async (dispatch_get_main_queue (), ^{
      NSLog(@"No notes");
      [[customCell viewWithTag:777] removeFromSuperview];
                });
}
```

Comment: Dear @Winston - this worked perfectly! Thanks so much! To better my understanding of iOS development though, please can I ask why putting this on the main thread did the job?

Comment: Hi Lavanya, I'm really glad that this worked for you! In every app that have Graphical User Interface (GUI) all processes that have to do with updating what the user sees need to happen on the Main Thread, what's why we never block the Main Thread with long tasks and we need always to update the views on the Main Thread. I hope this helps you.

Comment: This is just perfect - thanks so much @Winston. In fact, this explains a lot of functionality within my app that can be vastly improved with UI aspects on the main thread. Thanks so much for this - a massive help! Hope you have a great day!

Comment: You too have a great day. I also remember when I made this discovery, about the Main Thread. It was a huge break thru for me.